# Including the filename in a solr collection?

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfsearch, cfindex

Is it possible to index a file, in a ColdFusion Solr collection, and include the filename in a way that's searchable?

If I search for a filename I know is indexed, and a dump of the collection shows the key and url contains that filename, it brings back 0 results.

I tried adding the filename to the body parameter in the `cfindex`, but that doesn't work:

```
<CFINDEX COLLECTION="#CollectionName#" 
      ACTION="update" 
      KEY="#FileName#" 
      TYPE="file" 
      BODY="#FileName#">
```

I know you don't usually include body on a `type=file`, but I thought I'd try.